# Enable Disable JQuery Drag-able

Tags: jquery

I am working on a print form that will enable Admin user Change the lay out of the print form 
so i select JQuery Dragable for the job and its working fine but their is one problem  when 
Enable or Disable the first Element in HTML that is dragable take the Disable Style when Dragable is Disabled the other element keep there original look 
I am using IE 8 .
I run the code on Fierfox and Chrome and the result was that all the Element change their style to disable style. I need the Elemnet to Keep there original Stayl

```
function EnableDragAndDrop(cBox) {
    $("#divDoB").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divNationalNo").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divSex").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divPlaceOfBirth").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divIssueDate").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divMotherName").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divExpDate").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
    $("#divAuthority").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });
   $("#divPassportHolderName").draggable({ disabled: cBox.checked });

}
```

Comment: Could you reformat your code?

Comment: Could you tell me when EnableDragAndDrop() gets called?

On a different topic, why did you wrap every jQuery statement in its own $(funtion() {?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the IDs, if you just gave those same `<div>` elements a class, like `class="draggable"` you can make this *much* shorter, like this:

```
function EnableDragAndDrop(cBox) {
  $(".draggable").draggable(cBox.checked ? "disable" : "enable");
}
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: '#divDragArea', scroll: false });
});
```

Instead of `{disable: boolean}` you just need to call the [`"enable"`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#method-enable) or [`"disable"`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#method-disable) methods, this does that, depending on if the box is checked or not.  As a side note, you can place as much as you want inside a single `$(function() { });` wrapper, you don't need one for each statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all 
I found the solution 
when you call
$("#divDoB").draggable({ disabled: true });
the JQuery insert a Css class that will set the opacity to.35 
and that make the Item look in Disable mode 
so to keep the Same look and fell in both mode Enable and Disable 
I just set the Element opacity to 1
thanks for every one :)